# How to know details of an HEIC file?

Tags: metadata, image-processing

An HEIC file was sent to me via email. Is it possible to know when that particular HEIC file is created by the original user?

Answer (score 1):

The
[High Efficiency Image File Format (HEIF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format)
was adopted by Apple in 2017 with the introduction of iOS 11.

HEIF metadata can be viewed on the Mac with the Preview application in
*File Menu > Tools > Show Inspector*, to see the exif, tiff, GPS
and other metadata tags.
The creation date might be included in the metadata.

If you are not on the Mac, you might be helped by the website
[View and Edit HEIC Metadata Online](https://products.groupdocs.app/metadata/heic),
describing itself as
"Fast and easy HEIC metadata viewer and editor".

Comment: extremely useful. thank you

Comment: When a photo file is saved as an attachment in an email, then we can see the metadata (dates and all). When a photo is simply dragged and 'pasted' to the email (I am using google), the information is not seen using 'inspector' tools. Is there anyway to check this for the latter case.

Comment: Pasting pastes only the raw image bytes, as you can see by dumping the email. The image inside the email body is not in full file format and has no place for storing metadata.